# How to access .env file variables in TypeScript using dotenv?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm trying to use a `.env` file to store API keys in a TypeScript React project. My `.env` file is in the root of the project and I'm trying to access its variables from `src/index.tsx` via `process.env`.

`.env`:

```
FOO=foo
```

`src/index.tsx`:

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

console.log(dotenv.config()); // prints TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
console.log(process.env.FOO); // prints undefined
```

It looks like `dotenv.config()` throws in an error so I think that's where the problem is. Just not sure how to fix it. I've tried moving `.env` into the `src` directory and passing a path into the function, e.g. `` dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/.env` }) `` but still getting the same error.

`dotenv` seems to be the most common way to use environment variables in a Node.js project, but if there are better alternatives I'd be interested in hearing those too.

Any thoughts & ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the environment variable to `REACT_APP_FOO` and restarting `react-scripts` seems to do the trick. It works without calling `dotenv.config()`. Not really sure why it works this way so I would be interested to hear someone's insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access variables by first calling `require('dotenv').config()` at your project root. then you can use them like `process.env.FOO`.

You have to consider to call the `process.env.FOO`